# Unused dependencies should not be imported in application classpath

Tags: java, spring, maven, sdk, pom.xml

I have created a sdk which acts a library to generate api testcases .
Whenever I add my java-sdk dependency in the pom.xml file of the client application, those dependencies which are not in the client's application and used by java-sdk to add support for but are not used internally get imported along .

For eg: my java-sdk uses ApacheClient, so it contains the ApacheClient dependency for intercepting. But if the client is not using this dependency, it should not appear in the application classpath but it does.

I have created a multi-module project to upload at maven central , the module where all other module acts as dependency looks like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>java-sdk</artifactId>
        <groupId>io.keploy</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>keploy-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>keploy-sdk</name>
    <description>Client Java SDK for Keploy</description>
    <url>https://github.com/keploy/java-sdk</url>
  
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.keploy</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.keploy</groupId>
            <artifactId>api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.keploy</groupId>
            <artifactId>integration</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.keploy</groupId>
            <artifactId>models</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.keploy</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>1.49.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.49.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>1.49.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- necessary for Java 9+ -->
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.53</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.21.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy-agent</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.14</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
Footer
```

Comment: Either add excludes to your dependency in the application, or mark the dependency in your SDK as optional. The latter forces you to manually include them in every application that needs it though.

Comment: If they aren't required make them optional or provided. That way they don't leak into the client using it.